# Conditional Map contents in Mule ESB

Tags: mule

I'm trying to set 'set-cookie' header in `http:listener` conditionally - only when it's set by `http:request` which proxies HTTP Soap service.
AFAIK Mule supports ternary operator, and simplified map decalration syntax e.g. `[[ key: value ]]` so I try to return an empty Map if `set-cookie` is not set and correct Map with `set-cookie` in it if it's set

```
<http:listener path="/*" doc:name="HTTP"
            config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" >
            <http:response-builder>
                <http:headers expression="#[message.inboundProperties.['set-cookie'] == empty ? [[]] : [['set-cookie': message.inboundProperties.['set-cookie']] ]"/>
            </http:response-builder>  
        </http:listener>
```

The error response I get is

```
[Error: unterminated string literal]
[Near : {... cookie' : message.inboundProperties.['set-cookie'] == empty ] ....}]
                                                               ^
[Line: 1, Column: 58]
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.validate(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:268) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to proxy 'set-cookie' from the http-request down in the flow. Are there any alternatives (I'm currently stuck with server version 3.7 which does not support 'enableCookies' - also `enableCookies` does not always work because it creates global cookie instead of proxying it separately to different client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found a workaround to proxy cookies in Mule back to client
This is not general solution but if works for empty/singleton map

```
<configuration>
    <expression-language>
        <import class="java.util.Collections" />
    </expression-language>
</configuration>
```

Listener(which passes `Set-cookie` to client) in the flow

```
<http:listener path="/*" doc:name="HTTP"
            config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration">
            <http:response-builder>
                <http:headers
                    expression="#[message.inboundProperties.'set-cookie' == empty? Collections.emptyMap() : Collections.singletonMap('set-cookie',  message.inboundProperties.'set-cookie') ]" />
            </http:response-builder>
        </http:listener>
```

In my request (to pass cookie from client)

```
        method="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.method']" doc:name="HTTP"
        config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:header headerName="Cookie"
                value="#[message.inboundProperties.'cookie']" />
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
```

Comment: Trivia: forwarding SOAP requests of C# client works reliably only for Mule CE 3.8 (not Mule CE 3.7) because of [MULE-9029](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-9029) It has serious problems with 100-Continue proxying. Otherwise connection hangs.